# For-Loop exiting at the first round

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

Clarification: Goal of the code is to update a cell, based on the last update coming from the concatenation of three cells on the same row. The "X" is used to capture the updates of these three cells. I'm aware that in the "range" I'm selecting one cell at each time.

I wrote the following code (commented also the previous tries), but I realized I get only one line updated. No matters how many of them are correctly filled.

```
If Hrg.Row = Irg.Row And Irg.Row = Jrg.Row Then
    For i = 2 To Hrg.Row
        If (Cells(i, 11).Value = "X") Then
            S(i - 1) = Cells(i, 5).Value & " " & Cells(i, 6).Value & " [" & Cells(i, 8).Value & "] " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & vbLf & Cells(i, 9).Value
            cellname = "I" & i
            ' ws.Range(cellname) = S
            ' Cells(i, 9) = S
            ' Cells(i, 9).Value = S
        Else
            S(3 - i) = ""
        End If
    Next i

    cellname = "I2:I" & Hrg.Row

    For Each selectedCell In ws.Range(cellname)
        i = 1
        If (Not (S(i) = "")) Then
            selectedCell.Value = S(i)
            Cells(i, 9).Value = S(i)
            Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next selectedCell
```

Is there any reason why is exiting the function as soon as I've a "value" assignment?

Any reason why?

Excel 2016
VBA

Comment: can you please refer to which line the code fails on, and what is the error if any?

Comment: Hi mo.h,

the code doesn't give any error.
If I uncomment "ws.Range(cellname) = S" the program update the cell and exit both the for-loop and the function.
As it is right now, it updates the cell at "SelectedCell.Value = S(i)" and... that's it.
It does not even clear the Cells(i,11) -.-

I thought it was a cells.value issue, for this I used selectedcell.value... but nothing!

Comment: I don't know VBA but if I had to guess it looks like you are testing the value of an assignment by using a single equals operator instead of two `(Not (S(i) = ""))`

Comment: Joshua, that part works. Thanks for the try.

Comment: i do not understand what your code is trying to do or achieve, but should it not be `ws.Range(cellname) = S(i-1)`?

Comment: `cellname = "I" & i` makes cellname the address of a single cell so the `For Each selectedCell In ws.Range(cellname)` is only going to find one cell in ws.Range(cellname).

Comment: Please check the update on the scope of the code. I also put a simplified code in the answer below:
        For i = 2 To Hrg.Row
            If (Cells(i, 11).Value = "X") Then
                S(i - 1) = Cells(i, 5).Value & " " & Cells(i, 6).Value & " [" & Cells(i, 8).Value & "] " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & vbLf & Cells(i, 9).Value
                cellname = "I" & i
                ws.Range(cellname) = S(i - 1)
            End If
        Next i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a logical error in the second part of the code. You're resetting `i=1` no matter what:

```
For Each selectedCell In ws.Range(cellname)
    i = 1 ' <-- you're updating the same cell over and over again
    If (Not (S(i) = "")) Then
        '...
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next selectedCell
```

It is likely that you wanted to inititalize `i=1` *before* the loop and increment it after each iteration:

```
i = 1 ' <-- inititalize once, outside the loop
For Each selectedCell In ws.Range(cellname)
    '....
    i = i + 1 ' <-- increment i after each iteration
Next selectedCell
```

Comment: A good point. Fixed it.

Unfortunately, still, only the first line is filled even if I put the i=1 outside that loop.

Even with the simplified version, unfortunately I got always the same issue, but it's not working... and I'm not getting why.

Comment: For i = 2 To Hrg.Row
            If (Cells(i, 11).Value = "X") Then
                S(i - 1) = Cells(i, 5).Value & " " & Cells(i, 6).Value & " [" & Cells(i, 8).Value & "] " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & vbLf & Cells(i, 9).Value
                cellname = "I" & i
                ws.Range(cellname) = S(i - 1)
            End If
        Next i

Comment: @JinoLaTilla please take a look to my added part, did I guess right?

Comment: I debugged and Hrg.Row has the correct value of 4. If I put the suggested expression it goes from 4 to 4.

Ps. How can I upload a screenshot here?

Comment: Ok I see. Forget about this. Well to add an image, edit the question and click the image icon, or type `Ctrl + G`

Comment: I saved. Closed it. Reopened it with another name to put masked names and tasks... and now it's working!

No words!
Anyway, I'll give you another point :)
Thanks for the support!!!

Comment: @JinoLaTilla you are welcome. Glad to know that it works now :)